# Create daily temporary clone of Aurora cluster

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I want to create a temporary clone of my Aurora MySQL cluster to run daily ETLs (to make sure it doesn't affect the other services) and then terminate it once the ETLs are done.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')

old_cluster_identifier = 'test-etl'
new_cluster_identifier = 'test-etl-clone'

response = client.restore_db_cluster_to_point_in_time(
    DBClusterIdentifier=new_cluster_identifier,
    RestoreType='copy-on-write',
    SourceDBClusterIdentifier=old_cluster_identifier,
    UseLatestRestorableTime=True,
    Port=3306,
    DBSubnetGroupName='test-etl',
    VpcSecurityGroupIds=[
        'sg-xxxx',
    ],
    Tags=[],
    EnableIAMDatabaseAuthentication=False,
    BacktrackWindow=0,
    DeletionProtection=False,
    CopyTagsToSnapshot=False
)

reader_endpoint = response['DBCluster']['ReaderEndpoint']

response2 = client.create_db_instance(
    DBInstanceClass='db.t2.medium',
    Engine='aurora',
    DBClusterIdentifier=new_cluster_identifier,
    DBInstanceIdentifier=new_cluster_identifier + '-instance-1',
)

print(response2)
```

This code works well for me but then when I want to delete the clone cluster from the console, I just click on the instance name / Actions / Delete and this deletes at the same time both the instance and the cluster.

I tried to find the equivalent in the AWS SDK but if I run the function delete_db_instance() it only deletes the instance and keeps the cluster on with status 'available' so I have to do:
- delete_db_instance('test-etl-clone-instance-1')
- wait until it is deleted
- delete_db_cluster('test-etl-clone')

Is there a way to delete both at the same time directly?

Or can I just have the cloned cluster always available without any instance running and just create/delete a new instance everyday? I'm not sure there are additional costs if I just have the cluster without any instance and if the data will be up-to-date or not when I create a new instance the next day.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found out that I can just delete both the instance and cluster without having to wait in between:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')

new_cluster_identifier = 'test-etl-clone'

client.delete_db_instance(
    DBInstanceIdentifier=new_cluster_identifier + '-instance-1',
    SkipFinalSnapshot=True,
    DeleteAutomatedBackups=True
)

client.delete_db_cluster(
    DBClusterIdentifier=new_cluster_identifier,
    SkipFinalSnapshot=True,
)
```

And I tried to reuse the existing cluster but it only contains the data of the original cluster until the moment it was created.
So I will have to create a new cluster + instance each day in the end.